# Mod rewrite for opencart in lighttpd

Tags: mod-rewrite, opencart, lighttpd

These are the rules in lighttpd.conf

```
$HTTP["host"] =~ "^(www\.)?mysite.com" {
url.rewrite-once = ( "^/$" => "/index.php?route=common/home" )
url.rewrite-if-not-file = ( "^/(.*)" => "/index.php?_route_=$1" )
url.access-deny = ( ".tpl", ".ini", ".log" )
server.error-handler-404  = "/index.php?route=error/not_found"
index-file.names = ( "index.php" )
}
```

Everything works fine. When i open www.mysite.com/adidas it works, but when i try to open www.mysite.com/adidas?page=2 it gives me error404.

And when i try to open www.mysite.com/admin it gives me again error404, but when i open  www.mysite.com/admin/index.php it works...

How can i fix it..

Comment: I can't stand such bloated code. Add the $ within your `url.rewrite-once = ( "^/$" => "/index.php?route=common/home" )
url.rewrite-if-not-file = ( "^/(.*)" => "/index.php?_route_=$1" )` and it will resolve due to `route&product_category` or `&category` is missing.`$` grabs all the URL

Answer (score 0):

Found [this article](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/boards/2/topics/4569) which seems to answer your first issue. For the admin issue, I'm assuming you need to at least use `/admin/` including the second forward slash

Comment: I tried it.. but it doesn't work. And mysite.com/admin/ gives error404.